# Cannot use Braintree package I've installed

Tags: php, laravel, package, require, braintree

I want to integrate Braintree php libary to my Laravel project (https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server/php)

I've installed it with composer

```
require-dev{
  "braintree/braintree_php" : "3.11.0"
  }
```

But when I try to copy in the code such as I get this error in editor "Undefined class BrainTree_Configuration".

I've tried to require full path, put "\" before Braintree_Configuration: , "use" different paths
Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');

Comment: Done composer update?

Comment: `use Braintree\Braintree_Configuration` then `Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');` should work...

Comment: Done composer update, tried to remove and reinstall it again but no difference. 

Says undefined class on "Braintree_Configuration" from 
use Braintree\Braintree_Configuration

Comment: Can you provide some more detailed code snippets around the Braintree configuration? Regardless, I recommend sharing your code with the folks at [Braintree Support](https://support.braintreepayments.com) to get a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: It was my IDE that didnt recognize the vendor (phpstorm 9)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that both the Laravel and the Braintree docs are incorrect at the moment. In v 3.13.0 of the Braintree PHP package, the configuration class is `\Braintree\Configuration`, not `\Braintree_Configuration`.

I've just found this out and haven't completely tested it yet, but it looks like the only difference is the class name and namespace.

You can have a look at [the current Configuration class on GitHub](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php/blob/master/lib/Braintree/Configuration.php).

Also, if you're using Braintree with Laravel, it might help you to use their [Cashier package](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/billing#braintree-configuration), which will automatically include the Braintree package as well.

Just a note of warning, that the reference to the `Braintree_Configuration` class on this page is currently incorrect, as I mentioned above.

Comment: `\Braintree_Configuration` should still work. PhpStorm just doesn't see the class because it's aliased at runtime. See `lib/Braintree/Configuration.php` and search for `class_alias`.